# Asymptote working on Sharelatex but not on my local pdflatex

Tags: asymptote, sharelatex

I have a document.tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \asyinclude{test.asy}
  \caption{A test with \textsf{asymptote}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

And a test.asy file:

```
unitsize(1cm);
draw((0,0)--(5,5));
```

This is the output when compiling via Sharelatex:

[image: compiled with sharelatex]

This is the output when compiling via local pdflatex:

[image: compiled with pdflatex]

(the second screenshot has the caption at the exact center of the screen)

Why doesn't it work locally?

Comment: The compilation is (PDF)latex -> asy -> (PDF)latex.  Is it your case ?

Comment: I compiled by issuing `pdflatex document.tex`

Comment: First pdflatex compilation produces also an asy file, second asy compilation produces the PDF picture, third pdflatex compilation you obtain the final document.

Comment: Oh OK, I'll try. Can I automate this process in some way? latexmk?

Comment: Yes it is possible. I have a limited connection, search asymptote and latexmk. There is some tips in the asy distribution.

Comment: You can also use the `asypictureB` package, which calls `asy` directly from latex. But you need to enable `shell-escape` for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user O.G. I've found out how to make it work.

It's enough to create (in the same folder as the document.tex file) a file named `latexmkrc` with the following content:

```
sub compile_asy { return system("asy \"$_[0]\""); }
add_cus_dep("asy", "eps", 0, "compile_asy");
add_cus_dep("asy", "pdf", 0, "compile_asy");
add_cus_dep("asy", "tex", 0, "compile_asy");
```

Once this is done, it's enough to issue:

```
$ latexmk -pdf document.tex
```

---

Note: if you don't have latexmk, install it. If you can't install it, you will have to issue 3 commands instead of 1:

```
$ pdflatex document.tex
$ asy *.asy
$ pdflatex document.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, asymptote produces PostScript output. You have to configure the package for pdflatex by setting some variables (cut from the asymptote manual p. 162)

```
outformat="pdf";
```

See the asymptote documentation for the details where to put this (under Linux, it would be the file  ~/.asy/config.asy )